# Canvas Graph - Retrieve the data from Grafana

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, grafana

I'm monitoring data with Grafana and it shows me the graphs in a HTML5 Canvas element. I'm wondering if somehow I can access this data with JavaScript?

I understand that Canvas is a Graphic object but since I can interact with the graph, hover over a specific point and get more data on it, I assume it must somehow be possible to get this data.

[image: Interaction example]

Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to do so. Does anyone know if and how you can do it?

I checked the methods of the Canvas element and also checked the internet.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: The canvas itself just holds the image, think of it as something that can be "painted".  It holds no information about that image.  To get data associated to your graph you will need to figure out what is doing the drawing and where it gets the data to do so.

Comment: Makes sense, and now I also understand why the Canvas can't give back the data.
Should be from AngularJS, will check this

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas element is essentially a whiteboard that you can paint on. This means it is used for some fantastic UI and data representations like the graph you've referenced. It does also mean that you cannot see anything logical about the canvas other than its current image (amongst all the usual canvas functions to actually draw etc).

To find the data you need you would need to look to the JS that is bundled with it. However, if the data is coming from a service like Grafana then it is likely to have an accompanying API. Fortunately, you should be able to grab the data you desire by using their API.

Example request:

```
GET /api/datasources/1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJrIjoiT0tTcG1pUlY2RnVKZTFVaDFsNFZXdE9ZWmNrMkZYbk
```

Example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id":1,
  "orgId":1,
  "name":"test_datasource",
  "type":"graphite",
  "access":"proxy",
  "url":"http://mydatasource.com",
  "password":"",
  "user":"",
  "database":"",
  "basicAuth":false,
  "basicAuthUser":"",
  "basicAuthPassword":"",
  "isDefault":false,
  "jsonData":null
}
```

Read more at http://docs.grafana.org/reference/http_api/#get-a-single-data-sources-by-id

Answer (score 0):

> The canvas itself just holds the image, think of it as something that can be "painted". It holds no information about that image. To get data associated to your graph you will need to figure out what is doing the drawing and where it gets the data to do so.

Thank you @IrkenInvader

Answer (score 0):

you can export the graph data to csv or json file, just click the graph title, then the hamburger menu, then export